# Mechanicalsoup Proxy no python

Tags: python

A respeito de requisições em Python usando o mechanicalsoup, como faço para abrir o site usando uma proxy.

```
import mechanicalsoup

br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

site = 'www.exemplo.com.br'

open = br.open(site)

resp = open.text

print(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Através de [`session.proxies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908266/5686598):

```
import mechanicalsoup

br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
site = 'www.exemplo.com.br'

proxies = {
    'https': 'my.https.proxy:8080',
    'http':  'my.http.proxy:8080'
}
br.session.proxies = proxies

open = br.open(site)
resp = open.text
print(resp)
```

Comment: (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0316AC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'

Comment: @JhoonyFr0id "cannot connect to proxy" -> parece haver algo de errado com seu proxy.